Next.JS Middleware routing
I'm checking for the role and logged-in users to redirect them but it seems the middleware is not working correctly
this is my middleware.ts :
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { isAuth } from "@/utils/isAuth";
import { isAdmin } from "@/utils/isAdmin";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const auth = isAuth();

  if (!auth) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url));
  }

  const admin = isAdmin();

  if (!admin) return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/posts", request.url));

  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: "/dashboard",
};

but it seems the isAuth and isAdmin are not working!
this is the isAuth :
export function isAuth() {
  const authToken = sessionStorage.getItem("authToken");

  if (!authToken) return false;

  
  return true;
}


and this is isAdmin:
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export function isAdmin() {
  const authToken = sessionStorage.getItem("authToken");

  if (authToken) {
    try {
      const decodedToken = jwt.decode(authToken);

      if (
        decodedToken &&
        typeof decodedToken === "object" &&
        "role" in decodedToken
      ) {
        return decodedToken.role === "admin" || decodedToken.role === "developer";
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

i tried to use async for decode but didn't work.

Please ensure that the file is located in the correct directory
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#convention

What was the problem and fix? Please provide for further referanse. I guess you didn't have access to the session storage when running in the middleware but that would be nice to have the answer to the question.
